# Pdftk heap sections error when over 512Mb memory

Tags: pdf-generation, pdftk

I use `pdftk` server to automate various tasks. Recently I ran into a problem where `pdftk` crashed while merging a large number of pdfs with the error window:

```
Fatal error in gc: Too many heap sections
```

After receiving this error I've run some tests to confirm that this same error will happen, regardless of what task pdftk is doing on pdfs, when its memory usage exceeds 512Mb.

I was hoping someone could help me understand what this error means, and if there's a way to set up `pdftk` to handle these larger jobs?

If it's just a limitation of the program, does anyone have a suggestion for a similarly functioning program without this limitation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I know it's not perfect, but I just wrote my own implementation using [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) to fulfill my requirements. If anyone else runs into this post and needs it, it's available at [this github link](https://github.com/clapaz/MetCat) under the AGPL license.

Comment: the github link does not include any code.

Answer (score 0):

I used pdftk for dumping data, such as bookmarks/contents.  It is very useful.

However, I met similar problems.

Ghostscript may be helpful.

Ghostscript can change original PDF file into newer one, and decrease its size.

Ghostscript also split 1 large PDF file into smaller PDF files.

My commands are:

`gswin64c  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4  -dBATCH  -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE  -dDOPDFMARKS  -dFirstPage=(some number) -dLastPage=(some number)  -sOutputFile=newfile.pdf   originalfile.pdf`

Parameters such as `-dFirstPage=(some number) -dLastPage=(some number)`  may be skipped if the transformed PDF file is small enough

I wish the above could be helpful